# Grouping fs2 streams into sub-streams based on predicate

Tags: scala, fs2

I need a combinator that solves the following problem:

```scala
test("groupUntil") {
  val s = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2).covary[IO]
  val grouped: Stream[IO, Stream[IO, Int]] = s.groupUntil(_ == 1)

  val result =
    for {
      group   <- grouped
      element <- group.fold(0)(_ + _)
  } yield element

  assertEquals(result.compile.toList.unsafeRunSync(), List(10, 9, 5))
}
```

The inner streams must also be lazy. (note, `groupUntil` is the imaginary combinator I'm asking for).

NOTE: I must deal with every element of the internal stream as soon as they arrive at the original stream, i.e. I cannot wait to chunk an entire group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One way** you can achieve laziness here is using `Stream` as container in `fold` function:

```scala
import cats.effect.IO
import fs2.Stream

val s = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2).covary[IO]
val acc: Stream[IO, Stream[IO, Int]] = Stream.empty
val grouped: Stream[IO, Stream[IO, Int]] = s.fold(acc) {
  case (streamOfStreams, nextInt) if nextInt == 1 =>
    Stream(Stream(nextInt).covary[IO]).append(streamOfStreams)
  case (streamOfStreams, nextInt) =>
    streamOfStreams.head.map(_.append(Stream(nextInt).covary[IO])) ++ 
      streamOfStreams.tail
}.flatten

val result: Stream[IO, IO[Int]] = for {
  group <- grouped
  element = group.compile.foldMonoid
} yield element
assertEquals(result.map(_.unsafeRunSync()).compile.toList.unsafeRunSync().reverse, List(10, 9, 5))
```

be careful, in result you will get reversed stream, because it's not good idea to work with the `last` element of the stream, better way is taking `head` but it requires us to `reverse` list in the end of our processing.

**Another way** is use `groupAdjacentBy` and group elements by some `predicate`:

```scala
val groupedOnceAndOthers: fs2.Stream[IO, (Boolean, Chunk[Int])] = 
  s.groupAdjacentBy(x => x == 1)
```

here you will get groups with pairs:

```scala
(true,Chunk(1)), (false,Chunk(2, 3, 4)), 
(true,Chunk(1)), (false,Chunk(2, 3, 3)), 
(true,Chunk(1)), (false,Chunk(2, 2))
```

to concat groups with `1` and without we can use `chunkN` (like `grouped` in scala `List`) and `map` result to get rid of boolean pairs and `flatMap` to flatten `Chunk`s:

```scala
val grouped = groupedOnceAndOthers
  .chunkN(2, allowFewer = true)
  .map(ch => ch.flatMap(_._2).toList)
```

result grouped is:
`List(1, 2, 3, 4) List(1, 2, 3, 3) List(1, 2, 2)`

full working sample:

```scala
import cats.effect.IO
import fs2.Stream

val s = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2).covary[IO]
val grouped: Stream[IO, Stream[IO, Int]] = s.groupAdjacentBy(x => x == 1)
  .chunkN(2, allowFewer = true)
  .map(ch => Stream.fromIterator[IO](ch.flatMap(_._2).iterator))

val result: Stream[IO, IO[Int]] = for {
  group <- grouped
  element = group.compile.foldMonoid
} yield element
assertEquals(result.map(_.unsafeRunSync()).compile.toList.unsafeRunSync(), List(10, 9, 5))
```

Comment: When you chunk them, I don't think you're keeping the inner streams lazy? While this might give the correct result, I do need to deal with every element immediately as they arrive.

Comment: @Felix I updated answer to keep laziness of stream

Comment: @Felix do you know if fs2 provides any `chunkBy` or similar operation that can group the stream into chunks based on predicate? (`groupAdjacentBy` only groups the adjacent elements in the stream)